# Checked Checkbox in Yii2 Gridview by pjax

Tags: gridview, checkbox, yii2

I am struggling with gridview checkbox in gridview yii2. For checkbox,
I can use

`'class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn',`  which is extends from

```
'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
```

So, the complete code is in gridview :

```
  GridView::widget([
      'id' => 'crud-datatable',
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'filterModel' => $searchModel,
      'pjax' => true,
      'columns' => require(__DIR__ . '/_columns.php'),
```

Which is column.php is :

```
return [
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column) {

    }
], ... /*bunch column here */
```

My question is, how can I checked this checkbox by pjax. Because I have a data that came from pjax like this :

```
$js = <<<JS
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function(data){
        var datas = $('#print-sticker-keren').attr('data-print');
        /* result e.g : 2297,2275,2321,2317,2315
              I was wondering like function php's in_array.
        */ 
    });
JS;

$this->registerJs($js);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your checkboxoption check the value of checkbox if it active or inactive and add a class according to that status like

```
'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
       if($model->active == 1)
          $class = 'ticked';
       else
          $class = 'unticked';
       return ['class' => $class];

    }
```

and in your jquery function write

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function(data){
        var datas = $('#print-sticker-keren').attr('data-print');
        $('.ticked').attr("checked",true);
    });
```